# can one use socket.io for domain sockets?

Tags: node.js, sockets, dns, socket.io, ipc

I was planning on using socket.io to connect to my node.js client to a server using POSIX sockets.

The server is being redesigned to support domain sockets since both server and my node client will always run on the same host.

Can I still use socket.io module or do I have to look for some other module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no support for POSIX domain sockets in socket.io as far as I can tell from scanning the github projects. Your best bet might be to consider [coding your own engine.io transport and contributing it to the project](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io/tree/master/lib/transports) or just use node's regular socket support to send messages back and forth.

> Can I still use socket.io module or do I have to look for some other module?

Depending on exactly what functionality you are trying to build, there's a good chance just regular old node core socket functionality over posix sockets will get the job done. I wouldn't look for another module unless there's something significant to really warrant it.

Comment: I think the net package, part of core node, is useful. var net = require('net'); and the API net.createConnection(path) specifically looks promising.

Comment: Right, node can do domain sockets. They'll just be raw bidirectional pipes without any of the socket.io additional features (pubsub, "rooms", etc).

Comment: and supports bytestreams also?